# can we use "GoPro Hero 4" camera to shoot video tutorials or elearning courses or moocs?

Tags: camera, video-recording

Hello video stackexchange experts.

I need your help to know that is it good idea to use **GoPro Hero 4** to shoot MOOCs or video tutorials?

I have listed out few of the sample videos here.

Clay Animation Set Design

Lecture 1 | Programming Methodology (Stanford)

Justice: What's The Right Thing To Do? Episode 01 "THE MORAL SIDE OF MURDER"

Learn Malayalam quick to read,write and speak in 7 days Part 1

BALL IN AIR

Oyster Mushroom cultivation Jeevika Bihar

Azure Backup for Windows Client

Mould making,casting & firing casting mould-Ceramics

Thanks

Comment: Closed - I see you have asked the same question in various ways. Please use one question rather than ask it for each type of camera.

Comment: sorry if you feel that this is duplicate. but it's not same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GoPro may not be your best tool for this - it has a very wide angle lens, and is targeted at action and sports, mostly.

That said, you can still use them effectively if your scenes can cope with the distortion a wide angle camera brings. They are cheap and convenient. They cope well with various light levels, but the sound quality is possibly not as good as you'd like for interviews, for example.